# How can I successfully lookup hostname from an IP, but not vice versa?

Tags: dns, nslookup

Have a look at the following commands and their respective outputs:

```
$ nslookup 202.83.21.28 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Name:    broadband.actcorp.in
Address:  202.83.21.28


$ nslookup broadband.actcorp.in 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find broadband.actcorp.in: Non-existent domain
```

Why can I resolve the IP address `202.83.21.28` to its hostname `broadband.actcorp.in` but not vice versa? The way I understand nameservers work is, there should simply be an entry like `broadband.actcorp.in <-> 202.83.21.28`, or something like that. What am I missing?

Comment: interesting question. However, it's not that simple. A single IP can be mapped to multiple domains. In this particular case you've chosen an ip that is not properly configured in the DNS records. You can do a followup whois call to check why there might be such issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... there should simply be an entry like `broadband.actcorp.in <-> 202.83.21.28`, or something like that.

No, in general there are (at least) *two* entries:

- An `A` record for `broadband.actcorp.in` to `202.83.21.28`. This is how forward name resolution is performed.
- A `PTR` record for `28.21.83.202.in-addr.arpa` to `broadband.actcorp.in`. This is how reverse resolution is performed.

If either entry is missing then the corresponding resolution will fail.